# Automatically format Vec<u8> or [u8; N] as hexadecimal strings

Tags: rust

I have multiple structs where I want to format elements containing byte containers to hexadecimals strings. At the moment I have this implemented by overriding their fmt::Display in the following way:

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bar: Vec<u8>,
    baz: [u8; 2],
}

impl fmt::Display for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let bar = self.bar.iter().map(|b| format!("{:02X}", b)).collect::<String>();
        let baz = self.baz.iter().map(|b| format!("{:02X}", b)).collect::<String>();
    
        write!(f, "Foo {{ bar: 0x{}, baz: 0x{} }}", bar, baz)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {bar: vec![0x1, 0x2, 0x3], baz: [0x4, 0x5]};
    
    println!("Debug output: {:?}", foo);
    
    println!("Desired output: {}", foo);
}
```

Output:

```
Debug output: Foo { bar: [1, 2, 3], baz: [4, 5] }
Desired output: Foo { bar: 0x010203, baz: 0x0405 }
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1944f48353bb72f1dbf23413212f095e))

With multiple structs, this leads to a bit of duplicate code.

Is there a more convenient way to implement this? For instance a macro similar to `Debug` that handles `Vec<u8>` and `[u8]` as hex strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`derivative`](https://github.com/mcarton/rust-derivative) crate to add custom formatters for fields that you want as hex:

```rust
use derivative::Derivative;
use std::fmt;

fn format_hex<T: AsRef<[u8]>>(data: T, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    f.write_str("0x")?;
    f.write_str(
        &data
            .as_ref()
            .iter()
            .map(|b| format!("{:02X}", b))
            .collect::<String>(),
    )
}

#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    #[derivative(Debug(format_with = "format_hex"))]
    bar: Vec<u8>,
    #[derivative(Debug(format_with = "format_hex"))]
    baz: [u8; 2],
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=775753d60478c018a0d5b9ffcac754c0)

Comment: Rather than building up a `String` that is written out, it would be better to simply write directly to the output as you iterate: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=540fcc850342d3bd894e274ae059141d).

Comment: @eggyal True, I just copy/pasted OP's code to put together a quick example.

Comment: Sure, but how would one implement such a crate? Just pointing out another library implements such a feature xyz without indicating how they solved the problem isn't of very much value, imo, especially considering the short life-cycle. Customizing how debug outputs values strikes me as a very reasonable request without pulling in another package.


If rust doesn't allow customization of debug fields short of manually reimplementing the debug trait that would also be worth pointing out.


Short of the user actually using the "derivative" crate I'm not sure what value this answer has.

Answer (score 0):

One could use a Printer structure:

```rust
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bar: Vec<u8>,
    baz: [u8; 2],
}

struct PrinterHex<'a, 'b, 'c> {
    bar: &'a [u8],
    baz: &'b [u8],
    name: &'c str,
}

impl<'a, 'b, 'c> PrinterHex<'a, 'b, 'c> {
    fn from_foo<'d>(foo: &'d Foo) -> PrinterHex<'d, 'd, 'static> {
        PrinterHex {
            bar: &foo.bar,
            baz: &foo.baz,
            name: "Foo",
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, 'b, 'c> fmt::Display for PrinterHex<'a, 'b, 'c> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} {{ bar: 0x", self.name)?;
        for b in self.bar.iter() {
            write!(f, "{:02X}", b)?;
        }
        write!(f, ", baz: 0x")?;
        for b in self.baz.iter() {
            write!(f, "{:02X}", b)?;
        }
        write!(f, " }}")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        bar: vec![0x1, 0x2, 0x3],
        baz: [0x4, 0x5],
    };

    let result = PrinterHex::from_foo(&foo).to_string();

    assert_eq!(result, "Foo { bar: 0x010203, baz: 0x0405 }");
}
```